# not able to browse internet through wifi, but working fine with ethernet card

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

Hi I think I can get help from this page...

I am using ubuntu 12.10, I am able to access internet through lan wire, my laptop is also able to search my home router(wifi) and is also properly connected and shown as "connected".

But I am not able to access internet through wlan.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:8b:08:6b:33  
      inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::223:8bff:fe08:6b33/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:479 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:210353 (210.3 KB)  TX bytes:42731 (42.7 KB)
      Interrupt:17 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:00:c9:e3:df  
      inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::221:ff:fec9:e3df/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4237 errors:5 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:124699
      TX packets:4213 errors:13 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4447180 (4.4 MB)  TX bytes:575316 (575.3 KB)
      Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:4500 (4.5 KB)  TX bytes:4500 (4.5 KB)
```

plz help

Answer (score 0):

You can access Internet at a time one card may be wireless (wifi) interface or ethernet.
card.

If you want through wireless interface (i.e through mobile station) that time you should create bridge between ethernet card(eth0) and wireless interface(ath0).

```
ifconfig ath0 0.0.0.0 
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 ath0
ifconfig br0 up
```

Now your mobile will get IP address, you can access Internet successfully but your system (desktop) is not able to use Internet.
If you want then need to destroy bridge.

```
ifconfig br0 down
brctl delbr br0
```